# TypeScript function that takes an object without certain keys

Tags: typescript

Playing around with trying to create a function that takes an a single argument object that must not have some set of keys, without making people specify types manually. I was trying to leverage `never` somehow, but I'm getting caught up in trying to understand how inference works for function arguments that take in a type with a generic parameter.

```
interface ReservedAttributes {
    someKey: string
}

// evaluates to never if the type has a key that intersects 
// with the keys in ReservedAttributes
type ValidAttributes<T> = keyof T extends Exclude<keyof T, keyof ReservedAttributes> ? T : never

// This is correctly a never, but it doesn't address this problem
type Test = ValidAttributes<{someKey : string}>


// This doesn't work because the function argument ends 
// up being inferred as { [name: string] : string}
function foo1<K extends { [name: string] : string}>(attributes: ValidAttributes<K>)  {
    // ...
}
foo1({a: 'hi', someKey: ''})

// Roughly equivalent to the above
function foo2< K extends { [name: string] : string}, V extends ValidAttributes<K> >(attributes: V)  {
    // ...
}

// This one allows V to correctly evaluate to never, 
// but I'm not sure how to leverage that
function foo3< K extends { [name: string] : string}, V extends ValidAttributes<K> >(attributes: K)  {
    // ...
}
foo3({a: 'hi', someKey: ''})
```

How would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I'd first try staying away from generics and conditional types and do something like this:

```
type ValidAttributes = Record<string, string> &
  Partial<Record<keyof ReservedAttributes, never>>;
declare function foo(attributes: ValidAttributes): void;

foo({ a: 'hi' }); // okay
foo({ a: 'hi', someKey: '' }); // error, someKey
```

In this case, `ValidAttributes` is a general string-valued dictionary but with the keys from `ReservedAttributes` listed as optional properties of type `never` (optional properties are allowed to be missing, and properties of type `never` are not really allowed to be present, so an optional property of type `never` is more or less one that must be missing.) Does that work for you?

If you need to use conditional types in a generic constraint it can be done:

```
type Attributes<K extends keyof any> = {
  [P in K]: P extends keyof ReservedAttributes ? never: string
};
declare function foo<T>(attributes: T & Attributes<keyof T>): void;
foo({ a: 'hi' }); // okay
foo({ a: 'hi', someKey: '' }) // error
```

But it's more complicated and achieves similar results.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: That's very creative! I'm probably over-applying conditional types having just learned about them recently. Thanks for this. Are you using `keyof any` just as a short hand for `string | number | symbol`?

Comment: And why would you avoid conditional types in this case? Only because you think it would be harder to reason about?

Comment: Yeah `keyof any` is easier to write and also backwards compatible with versions of typescript where only strings are considered keys.

Comment: Conditional types and generics are harder to reason about, both for developers and for the compiler.  Meaning that you might find yourself having to jump through hoops to convince the compiler that an expression is assignable to such a type.  It’s not a huge deal either way, really.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is to have a type with optional properties declared with `void` type. No type is assignable to `void`, so any object that has these attributes will not be compatible with the argument type:

```
interface ReservedAttributes {
    someKey: string;
}

type DisallowedAttributes<T> = { [k in keyof T]?: void };


type AllowedKeys = string; // could be restricted if necessary 

function fn<K extends AllowedKeys>(t: { [k in K]: {}} & DisallowedAttributes<ReservedAttributes>) {

}

fn({ a: 'hi' }); // ok

fn({ b: 4, someKey: 'd' }); // Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'void & {}'.
                            // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'void'.
```