# Declare a type of "A function that returns anything except a promise" without using generics?

Tags: typescript, generics, conditional-types

I would like to declare that a parameter type is of type `()=>AnythingExceptAPromise`, and preferably without using generics.

```
// Declaring that a callback function MUST return a Promise is trivial:
function asyncFunctionCaller(f: ()=>PromiseLike<any>){
    return f();
}

// Works!
asyncFunctionCaller(async ()=>{
    return 5;
})

// Correctly errors:
asyncFunctionCaller(()=>{ // Good: Gives me an error: Not assignable to parameter of type ()=>PromiseLike<any>
    return 5;
})

// How do I type this so that I CANNOT pass a promise-returning function in?
// Do I need to resort to generics like so, or is there another way?
type NotAPromise<T> = Exclude<T, PromiseLike<any>>;
function syncFunctionCaller<T>(f: ()=>NotAPromise<T>){
    return f();
}

// Works!
syncFunctionCaller(()=>{return 5});
syncFunctionCaller(async ()=>{ // Correctly errors
    return 5
});
```

Is there a way to declare that syncFunctionCaller takes a function that does *not* return a Promise without using generics as I have done?

Comment: Why is it a problem if you get a promise? You can, for example, try to ban anything with a `then` method (basically the requirement for a Promise interface) but that can also exclude non-Promise objects that happen to have a `then`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment. Well, in this particular case, if I get a callback that returns a promise, it changes my assumptions about how that callback can be used. I'm deliberately not trying to go into specifics because I am distilling my question down to its most salient points. But since we're talking, and you've suggested I could exclude objects with a `then`, can you tell me if I can do _that_ without using generics please? That is the root of my question. Thanks!

Comment: @Taytay Why not use generics then?

Comment: I'm happy to use generics if necessary, but I was wondering if I was overthinking it honestly. I came across this question/answer where the answer was encouraging the questioner to avoid generics/conditional types, and the question seemed to be trying to do something similar, regarding _excluding_ objects of a particular type: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52618536/544130

Answer (score 1):

Typescript doesn't really have a `not` operator.

You can exclude things from a type (as you are already doing, which requires a type to start with).

```
Exclude<T, PromiseLike<any>>
```

Or you can test if a type is/has/extends something and then return `never` if you found a match, which also requires a source type to operate on.

```
T extends PromiseLike<any> ? never : T
```

But both those approaches require a source type, which require generics.

So I don't believe this is possible without generics because all approaches of implementing a `not` type require a source type to operate on.

Comment: That jcalz answer very clever. With that approach you could do something like: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=1&ts=3.5.1&ssl=3&ssc=11&pln=3&pc=3#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9sAggBQE5wLYEsDO0C8AUFFAEoQDGcqAJgDw7CpYB2A5gDRQCGLIAfFABkxKMm6pgWbgBs65KrToBrCCDgAzMemx4AMllV1eAriwgA3CKn78A3IUI1KMidA0BXFhSlwWUDTg4AAoJNgAuWAQUHVwIAEpIizgsGgdCQJCAbx4cGkiARgAmAGYoAF94jKDg8wB3bUw44NQIHDgZKyh8QSzK+KA I'm not sure I'd call that _simpler_ than the generics approach though... And you may get false positives on something like `{ then: 'a', catch: 'b' }`

Comment: heh I was going to come and make an answer for this but I see I already did a while ago.  False positives on `{then: 'a'}` is a possible issue, but you can always keep going, like instead of prohibiting a `then` property, allow an optional `then` property that isn't a function.  Oops, there's no "isn't a function", so how about "something with no `call` property"?  It's a fun rabbit hole, but yeah, any claim to simplicity has to be abandoned if you do that.  In practice I wonder how often people have properties named `then`.

Comment: Thanks Alex and @jcalz! Yeah, I'm happy to do something like preventing a callback that has a `then` property and noting it's imperfect....I'll give this a shot.